# Ruby Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) on Windows 7

Tags: mysql, windows-7, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mysql2

I am working on windows rails application . I have created rb file for that application.

I am able to connect to mysql via appliction but when I am trying to connect it via ruby code , error is coming for connecting mysql. I am working on the production mode .

Running production mode rails application openning the mysql connection but not rb file out of application . I am using database.yml to connect th mysql.

This system is working fine on the windows xp but not on windows 7
Here is a code

```
require "yaml"
require 'mysql2'
config = YAML::load_file("config/database.yml")["production"]
client = Mysql2::Client.new(config)
```

Here is the error

```
Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `database.yml` config file and add `host: 127.0.0.1`

```
 development:
   adapter: mysql2
   database: db/development.mysql2
   pool: 5
   host: 127.0.0.1
```